Convert C code to C++ code - for initialising an array of structures
The following code, written years ago in C, will not compile in the Community version of Microsoft Visual Studio for C++:
typedef struct {
    char* szString;
    int  iID;
}   LocalStringElement;


LocalStringElement l_sTheStrings[] = {
    {"Simple",      0}, {"S", 0},
    {"Triangular",  1}, {"T", 1},
    {"Weighted",    2}, {"W", 2},
    {"Exponential", 3}, {"E", 3}
};

Later on in the code it uses l_sTheStrings[some value].szString and l_sTheStrings[some value].iID, so it looks to be putting structures as elements of an array.
Using the C++ debugger gives, as an example,the following type of error message :
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [7]' to 'char *'
Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)

Looking at other answers, such as :
An array of structures in C
it looks like maybe swap char* szString to be const char* szString, but I was not sure if this is a sound thing to do and gives exactly the same behaviour as the C coding intended ?

The error message is clear. You need to use const char* instead.

The error message is quite clear: You can't use a char* pointer to point to literal string. That's because literal strings are constant in C++ (unlike C), so you must use const char*. Either that, or make szString an array, or use std::string if you really want to go C++.

Duplicate of 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Pedantic note: That error message is coming from the compiler, not the debugger.

Does this answer your question? extern "C" 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'

It is a sound change. It could have a ripple affect, forcing other things to be changed as well. There is also a chance it will trigger errors for some undetected problems in the original code.

There are compiler options to make literals live in writable space so that this would compile as-is.

Other options, since you intend to convert to C++,  would be changing to std::string_view or std::string. These would be a bigger change and force more code changes.

Why is conversion from string literal to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++
